# How to embed Scala in HTML?

Tags: php, html, scala

Coming from a background in PHP, I am used to the idea that I can simply embed server-side scripts into my HTML pages. Searching online, I haven't been able to find a simple `echo <h1>Hello World</h1>;` equivalent in Scala besides using a web framework like Lift. Can I do this with Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is an exception in being a language designed to be embedded in an HTML page. Apache has `mod_php` to do this for you. Scala, like many other languages, requires you to start up a web server to respond to requests and render HTML. You can use frameworks like Lift or Play, or you can make a Servlet-based app and deploy it into any Servlet container.

You *could* set up an Apache server to run CGI scripts and then insert a .scala file to be run by the `scala` command - but it would be incredibly slow as it would have to start up the Java VM every time. I wouldn't recommend that for anything other than scratching a mental itch.

Answer (score 4):

See [Scalate](http://scalate.fusesource.org/) and [PlayFramework](http://www.playframework.com/)

Scalate Scaml is very close to what you want

[image]

Scalate supports the following template formats

- [Mustache](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/mustache.html) which is a Scala dialect of Mustache for logic-less templates which also work inside the browser using mustache.js
- [Scaml](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/scaml-reference.html) which is a Scala dialect of Haml and is very DRY for generating HTML / XHTML
- [Jade](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/jade.html) which is an even more DRY dialect of Scaml for HTML / XHTML markup generation
- [SSP](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/ssp-reference.html) which is like Velocity, JSP or Erb from Rails

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to generate an HTML template with SSP.

Define an object that the template will access for data.

```scala
object FunStuff {
  val dinnertime = "eating stuff!"
}
```

Create a template:

```scala
<% import mrpowers.scalate.example.FunStuff  %>
<p>
    My message is "<%= List("hi", "there", "reader!").mkString(" ") %>"
    At dinnertime, I like <%= FunStuff.dinnertime %>
</p>
```

Render the template:

```scala
val sourceDataPath = new java.io.File("./src/test/resources/simple_example.ssp").getCanonicalPath
val engine = new TemplateEngine
println(engine.layout(sourceDataPath))
```

Here's the result:

```
<p>
    My message is "hi there reader!"
    At dinnertime, I like eating stuff!
</p>
```